# Bootstrap 4 remove caret from dropdown button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 3 you could easily remove the "caret" (small arrow that points down) from a dropdown button, I can't see how to do it in Bootstrap 4 though because they no longer use `<span class="caret"></span>`.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's done in css. Do something like that:

```
.dropdown-toggle:after { content: none }
```

Comment: You may need an !important at the end of that declaration depending on your load order.

Answer (score 72):

Simply remove the `dropdown-toggle`!

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ydnosrLw/

Comment: I think, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 37):

You can remove the caret in Bootstrap 4 by removing the `dropdown-toggle` class from your element. So instead of this:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" ...>
```

Your button will be

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ...>
```

This won't have any side affects and it will still function properly as a dropdown.

Answer (score 8):

In Bootstrap 4 you can remove caret form dropdown button by setting `$enable-caret` sass variable `false`. But you must set this variable before importing the bootstrap sass file.

```
// Your variable overrides
$enable-caret: false

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```